# Fix custom type definition python 3.7

Tags: python, type-hinting

I defined a type to use in my classes

```
FloatArray = np.ndarray[Any, np.dtype[np.float64]]
```

this is accepted when using python3.8

luckily I must switch to python3.7 and I am having difficulties redifining it to make mypy and python3.7 accept it.

I even tried

```
FloatArray = np.ndarray[Any, np.ndarray[Any]]
```

how do

Comment: Do you have an error message? What is the numpy version?